# A statement on complex polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

I have a feeling the following is true.

Assume that there are $n$ mutually disjoint closed disks $D_i$ in the complex plane and $n$ complex polynomials $p_i(z)$ of degree $n - 1$, with both types of objects indexed from $1$ to $n$, such that

condition: the polynomial $p_i(z)$ has exactly 1 complex root in each disk $D_j$, where $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $j \neq i$ and no other roots.

Are the $n$ polynomials $p_1(z), \ldots, p_n(z)$ necessarily linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$? I think it is true.

So for example, if $n = 3$, then $p_1(z)$ has exactly $1$ root in $D_2$ and exactly $1$ root in $D_3$ and no other roots, and so on.

If my intuition is correct, this problem should be some kind of "dual" to the problem where you have $n$ polynomials, say $q_i(z)$, of degree $n - 1$, where all the roots of $q_i(z)$ are in the closed disk $D_i$ (we also assume that the closed disks $D_i$, for $i = 1, \dots, n$, are mutually disjoint). I know how to prove this possibly "dual" problem using the Grace-Walsh-Szego (accents?) coincidence theorem.

I did not run any numerical simulations yet. Any ideas or suggestions? I came across this problem by thinking about the Atiyah problem on configurations of points.

Edit: the conjecture in this post was proved to be false for $n \geq 3$ by Noam D. Elkies (see his answer below). However, for a follow-up question, please see [On well separated circular regions in the Riemann sphere and complex polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426655/on-well-separated-circular-regions-in-the-riemann-sphere-and-complex-polynomials)

Comment: To be clear, you also stipulate that the polynomial $p_i$ does not have a root in $D_i$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Bma

Comment: Let $P$ be a least common multiple of the $p_i$, and define rational functions $Q_i$ by $p_i(z) = P(z) Q_i(z)$. Suppose we have a null linear combination $c_1 p_1(z) + … + c_n p_n(z) = P(z) (c_1 Q_1(z) + … + c_n Q_n(z)) = 0$ identically. Then $c_1 Q_1(z) + … + c_n Q_n(z) = 0$ identically. This requires the poles of the $Q_i$ to cancel, which imposes a number of linear equations on their residues at these poles.  I think in highly degenerate cases it will be possible to satisfy these equations, but I am still working through the details.

Comment: You might find inspiration in the proof constructions for convergence and root inclusion for the Durand-Kerner method. Adding a radius restriction proportional $1/n$ (times the minimal distance of the disk centers?) could, perhaps, sharpen the situation sufficiently.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thank you. I will look this up. Yes, I suspect it might be valid with some specific radius restriction, such as what you wrote, possibly!

Comment: @Malkoun If your original question was answered by Noam Elkies but you have a followup question, the usual practice is to create a new MO question containing your followup question, and link to the first question from the second.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I created a new post, as you suggested, and cleaned up this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The conjecture is easily seen to be true for $n<3$.
We give a counterexample for $n=3$.

Let $p_i = z^2 - \omega_i$ where the $\omega_i$ are the cube roots of unity.
These are linearly dependent because they're in the $2$-dimensional subspace
spanned by $1$ and $z^2$.  But their zeros are the sixth roots of unity,
forming a regular hexagon $H$ each of whose three long diagonals $d_i$ joins
the roots of one of the $p_i$.  Let $s_i$ be pairwise disjoint sides of $H$
such that $s_i$ is parallel to the corresponding $d_i$.  It's easy to find
discs $D_i$ such that each $D_i$ contains $s_i$ and is disjoint from $s_j$
for each $j \neq i$; for instance start from the discs with diameter $d_i$
and dilate each one by a factor $1.01$.  Then each $p_i$ has no roots in $D_i$
and exactly one root in $D_j$ for each $j \neq i$, **QEF**.

A similar construction works for $n>3$ using
$p_i = z^{n-1} - \omega_i$ where the $\omega_i$ are the $n$-th roots of unity.
Note that these $p_i$ are not only linearly dependent but span a linear space
of dimension only $2$, the minimum possible; moreover, their roots are all
on the unit circle, so a fractional linear transformation such as
$z = (z'+i) / (z'-i)$ makes all the roots real, which means that
the $p_i$ can be taken to have real coefficients.

Comment: Yes, definitely a counterexample. Hmm, let me think if I could possibly modify my statement, by for example replacing closed disks with something else... What is a reasonable "dual" of a closed disk? Or maybe I should add an extra condition? I need to think...

Comment: All right, I have other ideas, but they are sufficiently different from this post that they merit another post, but only after I think them through and do some checking before posting on MO. Thank you for your counterexample!

Comment: Even for three real polynomials like $p_1=z^2-1$ and $p_2=z^2-4$ and $p_3=z^2+1$ which make the hexagon irregular, it is still easy enough to find discs that contain "every second" hexagon side in this way. [See image](https://imgur.com/a/RZWREYP).